# Can't launch django per script (CronJob)

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I would like to start a script, which is using my Django project with a python script which first starts a virtual environment.

**FYI** The settings file has the same name as the project folder `proj`.

I wrote some kind of a script to start the script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
activate_this = '/home/myname/virtualenvs/proj/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
import subprocess

path = '/home/myname/proj'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

subprocess.Popen(['python', '/home/myname/proj/ext_scripts/my_django_script.py'] + sys.argv[1:])
```

The *actual* script imports like this

```
...
import time
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj.settings")
django.setup()
...
```

Which returns

```
ImportError: No module named 'proj'
```

Comment: you want one python scripts to start a script that's actually running in a different virtualenv?  first thing to look at is, can you actually run both from the same venv?

Comment: if not, no need for the `activate_this` hack, just call the virtualenv python in your subprocess: `subprocess.call(['/home/myname/virtualenvs/proj/bin/python', '/home/myname/proj/ext_scripts/my_django_script.py...`

Answer (score 2):

You should to learn about [django custom commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/).

**Then execute**: `python manage.py your_custom_command args`

**Instead**: `python /home/myname/proj/ext_scripts/my_django_script.py args`